# Add to Table and sending in HTML Format

Tags: powershell

I'm having a lot of trouble coming up with a way to properly add the data i want to a table I am looking for to a table.  I'd like to then convert that table to HTML and send it via email.  For the sake of the example, I am looking for things with a disconnected status but I am testing it using "connected" for now.

```
 $style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
 $style = $style + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
 $style = $style + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }"
 $style = $style + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
 $style = $style + "</style>"

 $resp = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $uri -Body $login_request -ContentType 'text/xml' -Method post
 [xml]$xmldata = $resp.content
 if($xmldata.LoginResponse.success -eq '0'){
     Write-Host 'ERROR: '$xmldata.LoginResponse.Failure.message -ForegroundColor Red
     }
     Else{
     $SCRIPT:session_id = $xmldata.LoginResponse.'session-id'
     Write-Host "Login Successful" -ForegroundColor Green
     }

 $disc_request = "<DiscoveryConnectionListingRequest session-id='$SCRIPT:session_id'/>"
 $resp_disc = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $uri -Body $disc_request -ContentType 'text/xml' -Method post
 [xml]$xmldata = $resp_disc.content
 $xmldata.DiscoveryConnectionListingResponse.DiscoveryConnectionSummary


 $table = @{}


 foreach($entry in 
 $xmldata.DiscoveryConnectionListingResponse.DiscoveryConnectionSummary){
if($entry."connection-status" -eq "Connected") {
            #add to table here  
 } 
 }
 $html= New-Object psobject -Property $table | ConvertTo-Html



 send-mailmessage -to "email" -from "email" -subject "Alert!" -BodyAsHtml "$html" -smtpserver server
```

The data i need to add to the table is:

```
 $entry.name
 $entry.'connection-status'
 $entry.'engine-id'
```

I just cant figure this out - its driving me nuts!  Any help is greatly appreciated!  I keep trying different methods and it wont accept multiple values with the same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are passing an empty object to `ConvertTo-Html`, so it produces nothing. You need to pass your objects to it in order to get the table you need.

```
$HTML = $xmldata.DiscoveryConnectionListingResponse.DiscoveryConnectionSummary | 
    Where{$_.'connection-status' -eq 'connected'} | 
    ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Property Name,'Connection-Status','Engine-Id' -PreContent $Style

send-mailmessage -to "email" -from "email" -subject "Alert!" -BodyAsHtml -body $html -smtpserver server
```